# How to fill fields with a single click on a table row with ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-native, asp.net-core

I am making an react application with a simple CRUD functionality. In my environment I use a framework called react bootstrap 2.

Link: https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/getting-started.html

I have a form that the user can fill the information:

```
<form id="car-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="hidden" name="carId" />
    <div className="row">
        <div className="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Brand</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter brand" value={this.state.brand} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Model</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter model" value={this.state.model} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>Color</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter color" value={this.state.color} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label>TopSpeed</label>
            <input type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter speed" value={this.state.topSpeed} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="btn-group mr-2">
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger mr-1">Save changes</button>
        <button type="reset" className="btn btn-danger mr-1">New record</button>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger mr-1">Delete record</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The user can add a car and this working fine with the .NET core backend. I have a function from the official react bootstrap 2 documentation to select a row.

```
const rowEvents = {
    onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
        console.log(`clicked on row with index: ${rowIndex}`);
    }
};
```

When I click on a row I get the right index number. Now when I click on a row I want to fill the fields with **data**.

This is my **handleChange method**

```
handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            brand: event.target.brand,
            model: event.target.model,
            color: event.target.color,
            topspeed: event.target.top
        })
};
```

It still doesn't work when I click on a row.

How can I fill the fields when I click on a row?

Solution I used:

[How do I programatically fill input field value with React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671082/how-do-i-programatically-fill-input-field-value-with-react)

Comment: on clicking on a row you want to fill that data in form right ?

Comment: Yes! all the information must shown in the fields

Comment: where you storing the data ?

Comment: The data goes into a SQL database and this is working good with the backend. I use **React bootstrap 2** see link in the post.

Comment: you are using the field values from this.state.  you can't change it without setState

Comment: Is there a way to get `rowEvents` inside the class? The documentation of **React bootstrap 2** is doing this way

Comment: try copying your rowEvents inside render()

Comment: Thank you! This is working now and I can see the data in the fields can you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `this.state.cars` is where you storing the cars data . On clicking on the row change your function to

```
const rowEvents = {
    onClick: (e, row, rowIndex) => {
                this.setState({
        brand: this.state.cars[rowIndex].brand,
        model: this.state.cars[rowIndex].model,
        color: this.state.cars[rowIndex].color,
        topspeed: this.state.cars[rowIndex].top
    })
    }
};
```

and copy your  rowEvents to  `render()`

Comment: Thanks for your time! I get the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` remember that the rowEvents is declared outside the class.

Comment: where you storing the data

Comment: are you using BootstrapTable component